# Incremental Load Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query like so:

```
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ColDate
    FROM TableA
    WHERE DAY(ColDate) = 1 
       AND MONTH(ColDate) = MONTH(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 16 THEN GETDATE() - 1 ELSE GETDATE()END)
       AND YEAR(ColDate) = YEAR(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 16 THEN GETDATE() - 1 ELSE GETDATE()END)
```

The query above pulls data daily into another table. Now, the issue with this query is that we have to manually change the `DAY(ColDate) =?` in the `WHERE` Clause everyday to pull the right data. How do I set my WHERE Clause to check the day in that month and pull data accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
WHERE DAY(colDate) = DAY(GETDATE()) AND
      . . .
```

Or, perhaps:

```
WHERE DAY(colDate) = DAY(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 16 THEN GETDATE() - 1 ELSE GETDATE() END) AND
```